# How to use vue3-perfect-scrollbar in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, scrollbar

I want to use `vue3-perfect-scrollbar` in my `nuxt3` project. I registered `PerfectScrollbar` in plugins directory.

plugins/scrollbarPlugin.js

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'vue3-perfect-scrollbar'
import 'vue3-perfect-scrollbar/dist/vue3-perfect-scrollbar.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.PerfectScrollbar = PerfectScrollbar;
})
```

in layouts/layout.vue

```
  <div class="layout">
       <Navbar />
       <Sidebar />
       </PerfectScrollbar>
          <main class="main">
             <slot></slot>
          </main>
       </PerfectScrollbar>
   </div
```

`main` is not rendering after wrapping inside `PerfectScrollbar` component.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a plugin as follows:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(PerfectScrollbar);
})
```

Also, you have closing tag before `<main>`

Answer (score 0):

With Nuxt 3, you can create a plugin to use `vue3-perfect-scrollbar`

```
// plugins/scrollbar.js

import PerfectScrollbar from "vue3-perfect-scrollbar"
import "vue3-perfect-scrollbar/dist/vue3-perfect-scrollbar.css"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(PerfectScrollbar)
})
```

Then you can use anywhere in your app:

```
<perfect-scrollbar>
   <div style="min-height: 1500px;">
      <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
   </div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```